# How Can we use BindingSource.Filter Property to get rows form row count 30 to 50

Tags: c#, .net, filter, datatable, dataset

I am using c#, datatable and bindingsource control.
If we have a column name called as Recordsn in the dataset then We can filter as shown below.

```
bindingSource1.Filter = "Recordsn >= 30 and Recordsn <= 50" ;
```

However,In some cases I donot have the Recordsn column .Since Recordsn is just the row count , I believe that we can do the filter without having to insert the Recordsn column in the dataset and still be able to filter the rows to get rows from certain starting row to ending row.
  Is there a way ?
  Thanks.
  Is there a way to do this on datatable if not possible on bindingsource 
  Note : I have used 30 and 50 to just make the question simpler , it could be any range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the *BindingSource.Filter* property simply has that filter string value passed onto the *IBindingListView* that is the source attached to the *BindingSource*. The format of the *Filter* string is dependant on the object that implements the *IBindingListView*.

As you are using a *DataSet* as the source it means you are actually binding against a *DataView* that is attached to a specific *DataTable* from the *DataSet*. Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) for the *DataView.RowFilter* property there seems no ability to filter against the row count.

So in short, the answer is no, you cannot do as you need. To get around this you could creaet your own filtering class that sits between the *DataView* and the *DataTable* and restricts the rows it exposes.

Comment: I intend to filter on dataset , is there other way than using BindingSource